# OpenUI5: PDFViewer shows PDF page on top of all other controls in IE11

Tags: iframe, sapui5, internet-explorer-11, pdfviewer

I am trying to show a dialog control using `sap.m.Dialog` on top of PDFViewer control in IE11. In this case, PDFViewer and dialog controls both will get activated at the same time.i.e., `z-order` of PDFViewer and Dialog control will become the same.

This limitation of PDFViewer is specifed at: [PDF Viewer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/cd80a8bca4ac450b86547d78f0653330.html)

To solve this issue, openui5 specify that we have to ***insert another iframe element between the PDF viewer and the rest of the elements on the page***.

I don't really understand the meaning of the sentence specified above. Can someone help me on how to insert another iframe element between pdf viewer and rest of the elements of the page.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Ok, added screenshot.  I also tried using iframe to display pdf doc instead of PDFViewer, but still issue persists in IE11.

Comment: What is the target UI5 version? Just to let you know, [UI5 already stopped supporting IE11 since v1.88](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933).